# Regression problem getting much better results when dividing values by 100

Tags: regression, scaling, loss-function, bert-language-model, mse

I'm working on a regression problem in pytorch. My target values can be either between 0 to 100 or 0 to 1 (they represent % or % divided by 100).

The data is unbalanced, I have much more data with lower targets.

I've noticed that when I run the model with targets in the range 0-100, it doesn't learn - the validation loss doesn't improve, and the loss on the 25% large targets is very big, much bigger than the std in this group.

However, when I run the model with targets in the range 0-1, it does learn and I get good results.

If anyone can explain why this happens, and if using the ranges 0-1 is "cheating", that will be great.

Also - should I scale the targets? (either if I use the larger or the smaller range).

Some additional info - I'm trying to fine tune bert for a specific task. I use MSEloss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your observation relates to batch normalization. There is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) written on the subject, an numerous medium/towardsdatascience posts, which i will not list here. Idea is that if you have a no non-linearities in your model and loss function, it doesn't matter. But even in MSE you do have non-linearity, which makes it sensitive to scaling of both target and source data. You can experiment with inserting [Batch Normalization](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm1d.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm1d) Layers into your models, after dense or convolutional layers. In my experience it often improves accuracy.